# Wheel fails for pyarrow installation

Tags: python-3.7, pyarrow, python-wheel

I am trying to install pyarrow on my raspberry pi but I keep running into "ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow". The full story is:

```
 -- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.7.3") found components: Interpreter Development NumPy
  -- Found Python3Alt: /usr/bin/python3
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:261 (find_package):
    By not providing "FindArrow.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
    asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Arrow", but
    CMake did not find one.
  
    Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Arrow" with any of
    the following names:
  
      ArrowConfig.cmake
      arrow-config.cmake
  
    Add the installation prefix of "Arrow" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
    "Arrow_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Arrow"
    provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
    installed.
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/tmp/pip-install-e_ekov4_/pyarrow_4e0f276b716a45f492872a9110cbdd84/build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-37/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  error: command '/usr/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Some background on the system: Python 3.7.3 is installed as well as cmake 3.16.3-3~bpo10+1.

I am aware of the fact that there are other posts about this issue but none of the ideas to solve it worked for me or sometimes none were found. The issue was discussed in the [wheel git hub last December](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/14920) and seems to be solved but then it seems like I'm installing the wrong version? I simply used `pip3 install pyarrow`, is that wrong?